# Error while installing glibc-2.14 from source

Tags: debian, compiling, package-management, glibc

The version of glibc in the repository is 2.13 so I couldn't use `apt-get` to install it. I downloaded the source code of glibc-2.14, but when I run `./configure` command I get this error:

```
checking for -z nodlopen option... yes
checking for -z initfirst option... yes
checking for -z relro option... no
configure: error: linker with -z relro support required
```

MySQL workbench relies on glibc-2.14. How can I get workbench installed?

Comment: You could do a local install of libc and link MySQL workbench against it, while leaving the system one alone (if possible). Replacing the system one with a locally compiled 2.14 may lead to bad things, and is not recommended. However, if MySQL Workbench is proprietary and expects the library location to be in a specific place, then you will have to upgrade to a newer version of Debian. I assume you are on wheezy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"testing" in Debian currently has libc6 2.19, does that workbench need exactly 2.14 or (more usually) at least 2.14... see [packages.debian.org](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=libc6&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all). I recommend updating your system to testing completely or to use pinning to selectively update packages.

Trying to compile glibc yourself is **not** something undertaken lightly, fighting the dependency hell while upgrading selectively to testing is a lot easier :-)